# Alter interaction with Higgs field

Tags: mass, higgs

Will it ever be possible and are there any theories of how we could alter particles interaction with the Higgs field? Could this be used to alter the amount of  mass of an object? If not why? Is it fundamentally impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contribution the Higgs field makes to the squared rest mass of a particle species is proportional to the squares of both a species-specific coupling parameter and the Higgs field's amplitude.

Usually, the Higgs field is at a non-zero vacuum amplitude that minimises the field's potential energy density. By exciting the field, it's possible to move it to a non-vacuum state with an unstable different Higgs amplitude, thus scaling all species' shift in squared rest mass. (Changing masses independently would instead require altering the coupling parameters, which is not possible in mainstream physical models.) At the electroweak energy scale, W/Z bosons can lose their mass because of this.

However, most of the mass of matter is due to binding energies (viz. $E=mc^2$) instead of the Higgs mechanism. Even if the Higgs amplitude were reduced to zero at a local maximum of the potential, this would not make hadrons massless because most of their mass is due to the strong force.